# Data visualization of human pose coordinates using TSNE

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, computer-vision, data-visualization

I have collected human pose coordinates using tf-pose. I have collected those for 2 actions: standing and walking. After preprocessing the data I am left with a list of coordinates along with the probability (list of floating numbers). For labels, I have given '0' for standing and '1' for walking. I now want to visualize the data using tsne before using the data. Considering 'x' has poses for both walking and standing, I am getting the following error:

> x.head()

```
    pose
0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.26, 0.38, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 0.27, 0....
1   [1.0, 1.0, 0.77, 0.66, 0.15, 2.0, 2.0, 0.73, 0...
2   [0.0, 0.0, 0.77, 0.59, 0.59, 1.0, 1.0, 0.65, 0...
3   [0.0, 0.0, 0.76, 0.59, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 0.65, 0....
4   [0.0, 0.0, 0.75, 0.55, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0, 0.65, 0....
```

> tsne_data = model.fit_transform(x)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-5ca44e55c85d> in <module>
----> 1 tsne_data = model.fit_transform(x)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    889             Embedding of the training data in low-dimensional space.
    890         """
--> 891         embedding = self._fit(X)
    892         self.embedding_ = embedding
    893         return self.embedding_

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py in _fit(self, X, skip_num_points)
    667             raise ValueError("'angle' must be between 0.0 - 1.0")
    668         if self.method == 'barnes_hut':
--> 669             X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=['csr'],
    670                                     ensure_min_samples=2,
    671                                     dtype=[np.float32, np.float64])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    418                     f"requires y to be passed, but the target y is None."
    419                 )
--> 420             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    421             out = X
    422         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    597                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    598                 else:
--> 599                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    600             except ComplexWarning:
    601                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

In which form should I convert this data to, in order to visualize it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.